# Use of FFmpeg in the project

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am taking some screens shot images and want to convert them to videos of some format. Iknw FFmpeg is the solution for this but I am unable to find the code for using it in my project and also am unable to find this library. Please give me a step by step process with details of  coding this.

Answer (score 0):

An example to help you get started:

```
ffmpeg -ab 256k -s 640x480 -f image2 -r .1 -b 180000 -i pics*.jpg -i coolmusic.mp3 final-video.mpg
```

Read the man page for further details.